# Let $p_j\in K[X]$ a polynomial of degree $j$. It is true that an arbitrary collection $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ is a basis of $K_m[X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Let $p_j\in K[X]$ a polynomial of degree $j$. It is true that an arbitrary collection $p_0,p_1,...,p_m$ is a basis of $K_m[X]$?

Here $K$ is a field and $K_m[X]:=\{p\in K[X]:\deg(p)\le m\}$ is a vector space over $K$.

I think the answer is yes but Im not sure. If the collection $B=\{p_0,p_1,...,p_m\}$ is a basis of the vector space $K_m[X]$ of polynomials of degree less or equal to $m$ then

$$\sum_{j=0}^m a_jp_j=0\iff a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_m=0,\quad a_j\in K$$

If $a_m\neq 0$ then exists some $b_mX^m$ due to the fact that $\deg(p_m)=m$. Then $a_m$ necessarily must be zero if we want that

$$\sum_{j=0}^ma_jp_j=0\tag{1}$$

But if $a_m=0$ then exists some $b_{m-1}X^{m-1}$ due to that $\deg(p_{m-1})=m-1$. Then recursively we can see that the unique solution to $(1)$ is for $a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_m=0$.

This proof is correct or something is wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Induction is usually preferred to recursion, but your idea will work in that formalism as well.

Note that this result does require that $K$ is a field, which is not terribly obvious from the proof as you've written it up. It's probably worth finding where you used that and making it clear.

Comment: Yes, $K$ is a field, I forget to put it in the question.

Comment: @Masacroso: Sorry if I was unclear: your *proof* should make explicit where this assumption is being used.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. I have defined a basis for a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ over $K$ as some collection $$\{v_1,...,v_n\}\in V:\sum a_jv_j=0\iff a_1=...=a_n=0, a_j\in K$$

Comment: Sure. My point is that it is possible to define $K_m[x]$ where $K$ is not a field. And it is possible to define a basis for such a set in precisely the way you've done above. But in such a case, it is *not* true that arbitrary polynomials $p_j$ of degree $j$ form a basis. Consider degree-at-most-two-polynomials of $\Bbb Z[x]$: the polynomials $(p_0,p_1,p_2)=(3,x+2,x^2)$ do not form a basis for this set. Your proof, as written, seems to translate to this setting... but obviously it does not.

Comment: You mean that the span of $(3,x+2,x^2)$ is different than $\Bbb Z[x]$ for some field or for any field?

Comment: Ah, I may see the confusion: is no field involved in my example. I mean that the $\Bbb Z$-linear span of $(3,x+2,x^2)$ [that is, the set of all polynomials of the form $3a+(x+2)b+(x^2)c$ where $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z$] is different from the set of polynomials with integer entries and degree at most two.