# Show that $p_0, \dots , p_m$ is a basis of $\mathbb{P}(F)_m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $\mathbb{P(F)}$ be the polynomial ring in one variable over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Fix a nonnegative integer $m$, and let $\mathbb{P(F)}_m$ be the vector subspace of $\mathbb{P(F)}$ consisting of polynomials of degree $\leq m$. Suppose $p_0, p_1, \dots , p_m$ are polynomials in $\mathbb{P(F)}$ such that the degree of $p_j$ is $j$ for $j = 0, \dots , m$. Show that $p_0, p_1, \dots , p_m$   is a basis of $\mathbb{P(F)}_m$. (Hint: Show that $p_0, \dots , p_m$ spans $\mathbb{P(F)}_m$ and deduce that this is enough. Also, keep in mind that the degree of $0$ is $-\infty$ by definition.

I know that all polynomials in $\mathbb{P(F)}_m$ will be in the form $p = a_0 p_0 + a_1 p_1 + \dots + a_m p_m$ with at most degree $m$.

I also understand how if I can show that the list $p_0, \dots , p_m$ spans $\mathbb{P(F)}_m$ then every spanning set can be reduced to a basis. However I am not sure how to link the two together.

It seems a bit too quick to assert that just because each polynomial $p$ can be written in the above form and the list $p_0 , \dots , p_m$ has the same linear combination, then $p_0, \dots , p_m$ spans $\mathbb{P(F)}_m$. Is that correct that this is too far of a jump to make?

Comment: (Same problem as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956749/let-p-j-in-kx-a-polynomial-of-degree-j-it-is-true-that-an-arbitrary-colle , but I'm not sure if two check-my-proof questions can be considered to duplicate each other.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  It suffices to show the $p_j$ are linearly independent.   But this follows from the fact that a polynomial cannot be written as a linear combination of lower degree polynomials.  Use the factor theorem:  a polynomial with more than $n$ roots is the zero polynomial.

That is,  suppose $0=a_0p_0+\dots+a_mp_m$.  Then $a_m=0$, since we have the zero polynomial (deg$=-\infty$).  Then $a_{m-1}=0$ etc.  Thus all of the $a_i$ are zero.   So the $p_j$ are linearly independent.